# Initializing a class derived from a base type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a class called an `Environment` which subclasses a dictionary. It looks something like this:

```
class Env(dict):
    "An environment dict, containing the parent Env (or None) where created."
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        # super().__init__() <-- not included
```

`Pylint` complains that:

> **super-init-not-called**: `__init__` method from base class 'dict' is not called.

What does doing `super()` on a `dict` type do? Is this something that is required to be done, and if so, why is it necessary?

After playing around with this a bit, I'm not so sure it does anything (or maybe it automatically does the `super` behind-the-scenes anyways). Here's an example:

```
class Env1(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__()

class Env2(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent

dir(Env1()) == dir(Env2()), len(dir(Env1))
(True, 48)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pylint doesn't know what `dict.__init__` does. It can't be sure if there's some important setup logic in that method or not. That's why it's warning you, so that you can either decide to call `super().__init__` to be safe, or to silence the warning if you're confident you don't need the call.

I'm pretty sure you don't need to call `dict.__init__` when you want to initialize your instances as empty dictionaries. But that may be dependent on the implementation details of the `dict` class you're inheriting from (which does all of its setup in the C-API equivalent `__new__`). Another Python implementation might do more of the setup work for its dictionaries in `__init__` and then your code wouldn't work correctly.

To be safe, it's generally a good idea to call your parent class's `__init__` method. This is such broad advice that it's baked into Pylint. You *can* ignore those warnings, and even add comments to your code that will suppress the ones that don't apply to certain parts of your code (so they don't distract you from *real* issues). But most of the warnings are generally good to obey, even if they don't reflect a serious bug in your current code.

Comment: @black -- thanks for that, it's super helpful. By the way, when adding a comment-to-suppress-a-warning, what's that called? `# pylint: disable=super-init-not-called` for example.

Comment: @Blckknght If you are inheriting from a class that implements the init method you have to call super in your class constructor otherwise you might experience unexpected behavior. This is not an option as you suggested, this is best practices and avoiding potential bugs

Comment: @NirO: It certainly *is* optional, or not doing it would *never* work, but as I discuss here, it *does* work with `dict.__init__` and with a variety of other types that don't do anything critical in their `__init__` methods. You're not wrong though that it *is* a best practice. That's why I suggest that calling `super().__init__` for safety is a good idea. You should only avoid it if you know a lot of the internal implementation details of the parent class (perhaps because you've written it yourself).

Comment: @Blckknght what is the `# pylint...` annotation called?

Comment: @David542: The [Pylint docuemntation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html) seems to use the name "disables" for comments that disable a check for a line or block. I've never used such a specific term, but I'm not a heavy Pylint user myself.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks, do you use another linter, or just none at all?

Comment: @Blckknght since python is a permissive language you can get away with a lot of things you usually won't be able to in other languages. Therefore it is especially important to follow best practices as guidelines more than just recommendations. Especially in this case where the implementations is not known and that although an error is not issued, the resulting undefined behavior could be very difficult to debug. Also, I don't see the logic in disabling the pylint warning in this case as calling the super init doesn't result in any overhead or interfere with the code logic.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `super()` is not required, but makes sense if you want to follow OOP, specifically, the Liskov substitution principle.

From Wikipedia, the Liskov substitution principle says:

> If S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of the program.

In plain words, let `S` is a subclass of `T`. If `T` has a method or attribute, then `S` also has it. Moreover if `T.some_method(arg1, arg2,...,argn)` is a proper syntax, then `S.some_method(arg1, arg2, ..., argn)` is also a proper syntax and the output is identical. (There is more to it, but I skip it for simplicity)

What does this theory mean for our case? If `dict` has any attributes (except `parent`) declared during the init, they are lost, and the Liskov substitution principle is violated. Please check the following example.

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = 1

class S(T):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent

s = S()
s.t
```

raises the error because class `S` does not have access to the attribute `t`.

**Why no error is in our case?** Because there are no attributes created inside `__init__` in the parent class `dict`. Therefore, the extension works well and does not violate OOP.

**To fix PyLint issue**, change the code as follows:

```
class Env(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__() # get all parent's __init__ setup
        self.parent = parent # add your attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

It does just what the documentation teaches us: it calls the `__init__` method of the parent class.  This does all of the initialization behind the attributes you supposedly want to inherit from the parent.

In general, if you do *not* `call super().__init__()`, then your object has only the added `parent` field, plus access to methods and *class* attributes of the parent.  This will work just fine (except for the warning) for any class that does not use initialization arguments -- or, in particular, one that does not initialize any fields on the fly.

Python built-in types do what you expect (or want), so your given use is okay.

---

In contrast, consider the case of extending your Env class to one called Context:

```
class Context(Env):
    def __init__(upper, lower):
        self.upper = upper
        self.lower = lower

ctx = Context(7, 0)
print(ctx.upper)
print(ctx.parent)
```

At this last statement, you'll get a run-time fault: `ctx` has no attribute `parent`, since I never called `super().__init__()` in `Context.__init__`

Comment: The code above works well on Google Colab.

Comment: Hmmm ... okay, maybe I need to update my environment.

Comment: @Prune -- works for me too on python3.9: `key 77`

Comment: No, it is how sensitive your environment is to warnings.

Comment: @KateMelnykova how would you do that? `$ python -Wdefault` ?

Comment: I found my problem ... an elder Python version and even older documentation examples.
Updating ... thanks for the checking.